# Any adjective synonymous to the following description

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

Is there an adjective meaning living your life as you want to etc saying, doing, behaving  and don't care what other people think about you? It can be formal or informal

I know the slang word "based" but it's very informal. urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Based

Comment: Your definition requires a verb (say and do ...). Please give an example sentence with a gap. 'Inconsiderate', 'insensitive', 'thoughtless' or 'self-centred', or perhaps 'disdainful' or 'dismissive', might work.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  If I could I would. The reason I'm asking I don't how to say it in English.  see https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Based the top entry. That's the thing. Living your life they way you want to (doing saying behaving acting and son) and not give a crap about what others think.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of suggestions that can be used, it may just depend on specific context.

If someone takes every day as it comes - Carefree? Insouciant? Nonchalant?

If someone wants to tell it like it is - Upfront? Frank? Honest?

If someone just says the first thing that comes to mind - Insensitive? Rash? Callous?

Comment: It's more like living your life in they way you want and not giving a crap if other don't approve. It's not exclusively about saying

Answer (score 0):

**[Headstrong](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/headstrong)**:

- impatient of control, advice, or suggestions
- directed by ungovernable will